# How can I move my USB-connected Time Machine volume to a server?

Tags: backup, time-machine

I would like to go from using an external USB3 drive for my Time Machine backups to using another machine on my network (either a small Linux machine like a Raspberry Pi, or perhaps a Mac Mini).

Is it possible to move the USB drive from my local laptop to the server?  Is there anything special I have to do?

[This question appears it may have some relevant clues](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/34391/3553) but it doesn't answer this question directly, and deciphering the clues was not straightforward. It's basically the opposite scenario.

These also do not provide answers:

- [Move existing USB Time Machine backup to OS X Server Time Machine](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/159693/3553)
- [How do I move a USB Time Machine backup to a Time Capsule?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/104277/3553)

Is it simply a matter of using `tmutil` to change the destination?